# Mysql один запрос из четырех таблиц

Tags: mysql

Пишу систему подсчета и перераспределения трафика.

В базе(mysql) имеются таблицы `sites`, `ins`, `outs`, `clicks`.

Таблица `sites` иммет поля `id` и `domain`

Таблицы `ins` `outs` `clicks` имеют поля `site_id` `created`

Возможно ли одним запросом получить все данные из таблицы `sites` + получить количество `ins`, `outs`, `clicks`, созданные за последние 3600 и 86400 секунд, принадлежащие каждому из сайтов?

Comment: Возможно. Так а в чем ваш вопрос состоит, что у вас не получается сделать из того что вы пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется проще будет использовать подзапросы с выборкой количества

Основной запрос:

```
SELECT `sites`.*,
(<SUB_SELECT>) AS `ins_count`,
(<SUB_SELECT>) AS `outs_count`,
(<SUB_SELECT>) AS `click_count`
FROM `sites`
WHERE 1;
```

Подзапрос `<SUB_SELECT>`, например для количества кликов за последние 3600 секунд:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `clicks`
WHERE `site_id` = `sites`.`id`
AND `created` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Специфика проверки времени "за последние 3600 секунд" зависит от формата поля `created`, оно может быть TIMESTAMP или INT или что-то еще, смотрите сами, как у вас

Полный запрос выглядит ужасно и не понятно, но я рискну его привести:

```
SELECT `sites`.*,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ins`
    WHERE `site_id` = `sites`.`id`
    AND `created` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
) AS `ins_count`,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `outs`
    WHERE `site_id` = `sites`.`id`
    AND `created` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
) AS `outs_count`,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `clicks`
    WHERE `site_id` = `sites`.`id`
    AND `created` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
) AS `click_count`
FROM `sites`
WHERE 1;
```

В итоге имеем в результате все поля `sites` и 3 дополнительные поля из подзапросов с количеством. Если нужно еще три поля с количеством за последние 86400, вы знаете что делать

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!